# Why do we say "who you were" and not "whom you were"? Isn't it the object of the verb?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, objects, whom, be

I have a grammar which says that "whom" is used when it follow a preposition.

E.g: *to whom am I speaking. to whom it may concern.*

The grammar also says that "whom" is the object form of "who".
E.g. *He was a person whom everyone regarded as trustworthy.* (*Whom* is the object in the sentence.) "However, this is now felt to be excessively formal by most speakers and who is commonly used instead." (VINCE, M. and SUNDERLAND, P.,2003).

I'm reading "Inferno" and there is this sentence: 
"Nobody had any idea **who** you were (...)"

Wouldn't that be **whom**? Is "who" in that sentence an object? *You* is the subject and *who* would be the object.

Comment: @Araucaria Now that you have rewritten the question, it's reopened. Yes, I could explain that, and I'll try and find some time to do it justice. Unless you get there first...

Comment: @AndrewLeach Erm (sheepish grin), I think I misread the question ... Apologies.

Comment: Would you please provide more of the excerpt? For that can affect the answer, e.g. *""Nobody had any idea who you were."* vs *""Nobody had any idea who you were trying to kill."* :)

Answer (score 3):

*Who* in the clause *who you were* is not the object of *you*. Only transitive verbs can have an object; and the verb *to be* is not transitive. It is a copula verb that "*links the subject to a subject-related predicative complement†*". For this reason *who* is correct in the sentence: *Nobody had any idea who you were*.

†The definition of *copula* in the *Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar*, p102.

Comment: @Araucaria. Not sure I'm understanding your question. Strictly, it _does_ need to be _whom_ (objective case) after a preposition - although a quick Google throws up examples such as "_To who do I have to communicate my arrival details?_"

Comment: Sorry Shoe, I misread the question!

Answer (score 1):

Who<sub>1</sub> are you? (*who*<sub>1</sub> is to mean nominative.)

Whom<sub>4</sub> have you met? (*Whom*<sub>4</sub> is accusative.)

As nouns have identical forms in nominative and accusative and as English has only a few pronoun forms with a special accusative (*he × him, she × her, who*<sub>1</sub> × *whom*<sub>4</sub>)
*whom*<sub>4</sub> was shortened to *who* (dropping the *m*). For learners it is a bit difficult to distinguish *who*<sub>1</sub> and *who*<sub>4</sub>, but it can't be helped: you have to learn it.

In the sentence "Nobody had any idea who you were" you have *who*<sub>1</sub> and not *who*<sub>4</sub>.

In the present tense the sentence would be:
"Nobody knows/has any idea who<sub>1</sub> you are."
*Who*<sub>4</sub>/*whom*<sub>4</sub> would not make any sense.

Ultimately the subordinate clause contains the question: "Who<sub>1</sub> are you?"

Comment: Hi Roger. Sorry, but none of this can be correct. In "Who are you" the word "who" is not the subject, but the complement of the verb. Consider "Who is she" versus "*Who is her" - the latter being wrong outside of an echo question, and clearly showing the last word to be in accusative case. Secondly, even in the third example the "who" is still the complement, not the subject. It is clearly "you" that is the subject. Consider "Nobody had any idea who she was" versus "*Nobody had any idea who her was".

Comment: @Araucaria - I changed my formulation. I deleted "subject case or nominative" and say only "nominative".

Comment: Hmm, but in the first example *who*  is not the subject!. *You* is the subject! Even in *Nobody knows who you are*, "who" is the complement of the verb. "you" is the subject!!

Comment: @Araucaria - I don't talk about what is the subject, I say who1 is a nominative and no accusative. A nominative can be subject or a complement after to be. The original question was whether who1 is correct or who4/whom4. The question was not what the subject is.

Comment: But the point is that "who1" *is* "who4"! *Who1* is not nominative, it is plain case - i.e. it could be plain or it could be accusative, it cannot be nominative.

Comment: Sorry, I have never heard of a plain case and don't need such a term in grammar. Compare German which has two different forms: wer, nominative and wen, accustive. "Who is it" is "Wer ist es" and not "wen ist es". Wen would be nonsense.

Comment: Yes, but German doesn't work the same way as English. Consider: "That's me".

Comment: @Araucaria -Yes, that is not parallel to German, because it is French C'est moi (It's my person) or Latin Est mea persona. And even Germans understand this. And actually, this moi or mea persona is a nominative (complement after to be). And even if in English this me is taken for an accusative that is not the correct thing as it is just an imitation of French moi (nominative in the phrase C'est moi).

Comment: Not quite, the situation in English is that "who" is *only* nominative when it is the subject of a tensed verb. All other pronouns which aren't the subject will be in 'accusative' case. It's not an imitation of anything :)